# Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified on LUBUNTU

Tags: lubuntu, display

I just recently installed Lubuntu-Minimal on my laptop and I downloaded firefox to test with that. when I try to open it using firefox in the terminal I get the Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified.

I tried googling it and it told me to echo $DISPLAY but that returned nothing.

I ended up installing lubuntu-desktop and set it back to open to the terminal on boot but I still get the same problems when trying to run firefox.

I can run startx from the console and it'll boot me to the desktop and everything will work from there.

How can get I firefox (or any other program) to start from the console? (I'm trying to learn gui-less linux)

Version 18.04

Comment: You haven't given your release  (`lubuntu-desktop` will result in different desktops depending on your release version!).

Comment: You need some kind of graphical environment (an X server or possibly a framebuffer device) in order to display a graphical client

Comment: I'm running Lubuntu-miminal 18.04; Would I run an X server from the console and then I can run graphical clients from there? Right now for me to run the programs I would just do startx and do it from there but I kinda wanna eliminate that

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Lubuntu-minimal as there is no package of that name; https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/lubuntu-core is closest, but you could mean the old netboot mini.iso?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall.  You seem to want the benefits of X without running X?  There are text alternatives to firefox that don't need X, eg. `w3m`, `lynx` etc. and simpler stacks than LXDE (which adds GTK+2 etc on top of X) but I'm not sure what you're after and what you're trying to accomplish using Lubuntu.

Comment: I just Lubuntu is really light and yeah its the minimal install. So yeah I want to be able to run X without actually being on the desktop so I can work and do everything from the terminal. Not just firefox specifically but IDEs, such as VSC or netbeans and Pico-8 for some examples

Comment: You can't run graphical application programs without running at least the basics of X, for example with a window manager (if you don't want the whole desktop environment). Lubuntu uses **Openbox**, and you can use it instead of the whole LXDE in 18.04 LTS. You can also use **Fluxbox** or some other simple window manager, but without it you cannot run Firefox and other graphical application programs.

Comment: Cool I will give Openbox a shot; thanks for the suggestions!